# Create git repository after project creation

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4, repository

I know there's an option to make a local repository for your project when you first create it, but is there an option create a repository after you've created your project?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, just run the following command in your project directory:

```
git init
```

This will create the `.git` directory containing an empty repository. Then, add and commit your files.

Comment: when I am trying to use git init i am getting -bash: git: command not found. can you please help me on this. I am using xcode 4.2

Comment: @chaitanyakiranThandu Make sure you have installed the 'Command Line Tools'. You can find them under _Xcode_ > _Preferences_ > _Downloads_ > _Components_. Click the **Install** button next to **Command Line Tools**.

Answer (score 4):

In the command prompt, make sure you're in the desired directory and perform a `git init` and you will have created an empty repository.

You can then proceed to add the files and directories to the repository by doing

```
git add <filename1> <filename2> ...
```

or you can select whole directories and use `*` to act as a wild card of sorts.

```
git add ./*
```

If you have any more questions check out these pages:

- http://gitref.org/creating/
- http://gitref.org/basic/#add

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You should go to your Xcode menu, click **Source Control** > **Create Working Copy**...

Xcode will automatically create your **.git** folder repository.

Good luck, and make sure you have a backup of your project before trying something else.

Comment: Works but create a .gitignore file first.